# How to change the color of volume when it is larger than previous and next bar?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to have a code that when the volume is higher than next and previous bar its color changes.
I wrote the following code, but the results does not make sense.
I used `offset` to shift the plot since I am mainly one bar behind since I am checking `volume[1]`, but not sure what is wrong. Am I missing something?

```
//@version=5
indicator("vol",overlay = false)

peakHigh = bool(na)
peakHigh := volume[1] > volume[0] and volume[1] > volume[2] 

plot(volume, style=plot.style_columns, color=peakHigh, color.red:color.new(color.gray,50),title="Volume",offset = 1)
```

Results look at below, but it is wrong
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are plotting `volume` which you should not. Your reference is `volume[1]` so you need delayed information.

Plot `volume[1]` and use `offset=-1` (if you want the volume bars to align).

```
//@version=5
indicator("vol",overlay = false)

peakHigh = volume[1] > volume[0] and volume[1] > volume[2] 

plot(volume[1], style=plot.style_columns, color=peakHigh ? color.red : color.new(color.gray,50),title="Volume", offset=-1)
```

[image]